# Draw behind hidden status bar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

To make sure the problem is not in my own code, I have created a new, empty project with a very basic `MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // enable full screen:
        // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets#insets-setup
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        // enable immersive mode:
        // https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive
//        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.peekDecorView()).apply {
//            hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
//            systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
//        }

        setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Red)) {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When `WindowInsetsControllerCompat` is commented out (like in the example above), the result is as expected - the content is drawn behind the status and navigation bars:

[image: status bar visible]

When `WindowInsetsControllerCompat` is uncommented I would expect the content to be drawn behind the status bar and cutout (just like on the picture above) with the status bar icons hidden. Instead I get the black area where nothing is drawn:

[image: status bar hidden]

I have confirmed this behavior both on emulator and a physical device.

My question is: using Jetpack Compose, how can I achieve this effect?:

[image: status bar expected behavior]

Comment: You just need to enable ```enableEdgeToEdge()``` nothing else because when you handle ```WindowInset``` on yourself you need to manage other things as well. so simply just use ```nableEdgeToEdge()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/display-cutout#best-practices

> Use `shortEdges` or `never` cutout modes if your app needs to transition into and out of immersive mode. **Default cutout behavior can cause content in your app to render in the cutout area while the system bars are present, but not while in immersive mode.**

So to allow drawing behind a hidden system bar `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES` is required:

```
    enableEdgeToEdge()

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).apply {
        hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
        systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
    }

    setContent {
        ...
    }
```